# Downloading option for android

Tags: android, android-webview

In HTML5 I often use below technique to download something; it works even if it's an image.

```
<a href="beauty.jpg" download="BeautyPhoto">Download Beauty Photo</a>
```

But how to do it into android app if I want to use `webview` from internal resource (say `asset` folder). Any suggestion please...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to load an image or something placed in asset folder into your webview. For that you need to use loadUrl() and provide asset path like this:

mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/WebContent/abc.img);

Comment: This way an image will be shown on the screen. But I want the image to be downloaded into user's phone so, he can use it to other purpose.